# How to write command output to CSV file in Javascript

Tags: java

I want to parse command output and write it into CSV file.
Following is my code :

```
try (final InputStream output = channel.getInputStream()) {
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(output));

br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is how i would write csv files. http://demeranville.com/writing-csv-using-jackson-csvmapper-mixin-annotations/

Comment: Also: this is a Java question, not JavaScript. Please edit the tag appropriately (there are other pending edits, so I can't).